# raspberry pi static ip vs discovery?

Tags: cordova, raspberry-pi, service-discovery

I have a headless raspberrypi that is configurable through a webserver running on it. In order to access it I need to allow users to access it via a network. 
The prospected users are not very tech savy and it should therefore be with as little manual configuration as possible.

Two options that I can think of:

1. The pi is an access point with a static ip (e.g. ssid: pi , ip: 192.168.3.14)
   The user connects to the wifi and configures the pi to use the users home network. He then connects to his home network and keeps using the same static ip.

Problem: What if there are any ip conflicts between the pi and the home network infrastructure?

2. The pi uses a dynamic ip and the user downloads a cordova app that scans the network to find the pi. Once found, the app just loads the page from the ip address webserver into a webview.

Problem: How can I discover the pi from within a cordova app?

I would prefer option 1 since it does not require the user do download an app.
However I am concerned about ip conflicts and therefore think that only option 2 would work. How do other manufacturers work this out?

Comment: Just use [avahi](https://avahi.org/) to publish a name via mDNS.  This will be usable by most modern clients (os x/windows/linux configured with mdns support).

Comment: @larsks How would the end user use it for discovery, I do not want them having to use the console or  3rd party apps. It should either be a static IP that I can print in the docs or an integration in android/iOS  app that can discover other devices.

Comment: This is a very common problem with RPi development. I think the only _universal_ way to solve this problem is to provide an alternative means of interaction, e.g., a two-line LCD display and buttons. I've implemented complete menu-based configuration systems this way, but it's an awful lot of work.

Comment: @chris they would just use the name like any other hostname.  E.g., if your pi was registering the name 'myapp', then they would contact it using the hostname `myapp.local` (in a browser, etc). But I may have lied about Windows supporting mDNS, so I guess try it out first and see what happens.